# List files before a specific date in bash

Tags: bash, files, timestamps

How to list files before a specific date in bash?

Comment: Did you try google? https://goo.gl/SWdqPz

Comment: give us details on what have you tried and how did it fail.. you can use `find` command, for ex:  `find -mtime +7` to print files that were modified more than seven days back in current directory

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://serverfault.com/a/122831

Answer (score 1):

You cant see when the file was created due to most filesystems does not save creation date (ext3 ext4).

You can use `find location -ctime time_period`

eg: With `-15` as time period you will see the files modified less than 15 days ago. `+15` files modified more than 15 days ago, and just `15` files modified exactly 15 days ago.

`-c` flag shows when last permissions where changed.

`-a` flag shows most recent access date.

`-m` flag shows the last modification date.

You can also use this (for modification date) to find files by specific date:

`find location -type f -ls |grep '10 Sep'`
 You should change 10 Sep with your desired date.